# Cannot call 'ta.sma' with argument 'length'='smoothD'. An argument of 'input float' type was used but a 'series int' is expected

Tags: pine-script, floating

Totally new here. Can someone help decipher the following error? I am trying to plot the following information on a graph:

Cannot call 'ta.sma' with argument 'length'='smoothD'. An argument of 'input float' type was used but a 'series int' is expected.

```
//@version=5
strategy("FingersCrossed Signals", overlay=true)

//ta.ema
ema3 = ta.ema(close,9)
ema4 = ta.ema(close,21)
long_ema = ta.crossover(ema3,ema4)
short_ema = ta.crossover(ema4,ema3)

//stochrsi
smoothK = input.float(3, minval=1)
smoothD = input.float(3, minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.float(14, minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.float(14, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")

rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)

data = (60-k[1])/2
data2 = (k[1]-40)/2

long_stoch = k[1] >= d[1] and k[2] <= d[2] and k <= 60 and k >= 10
short_stoch = k[1] <= d[1] and k[2] >= d[2] and k >= 40 and k <= 95

//entries
if (long_ema) 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
if (ema3 > ema4 and long_stoch) // ema3 > ema4 means that crossover was already and uptrend is continuing 
    strategy.entry("buy+1", strategy.long)
if (short_ema) 
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? You need to use an `int` but you are passing a `float`.

There is a difference between `int` and `float`. You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#id2) to get to know with the data types in pinescript.

You `float` inputs do not make any sense as `float` as they are `length`s. Change them to `int` and you will be good.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!